# saving rsync password for cron jobs

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, rsync

I'm writing a cron job that uses rsync and ssh to sync things up, but the problem is, rsync requires password when connecting to the remote server. i need to save the rsync ssh password, so it can keep syncing without asking for the password. Is there any way to do that? or is it just impossible?

Comment: I have found this link very useful: http://www.stardothosting.com/blog/2009/06/ssh-key-based-authentication/

Answer (score 2):

Use Generate the authentication key
http://www.debian-administration.org/article/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password

Comment: Please do not provide link-only-answers. SO should be the endpoint of searching.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow these steps to get your task done. Use commands mentioned below.

Step 1) You can use `ssh-keygen -t rsa`  to generate RSA public key.

Step 2) `ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@destination_IP_address`

( This copies the public key to remote machine , now your local machine knows your remote machine.)

( Note: make sure you are using appropriate "user" across machines. )